# Username lost after account connections

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, display-names

Hi!

I lost my username, which was wishi_ when I wanted to connect my askubuntu account with my stackoverflow account and with superuser.
Can I get it again? :)

Comment: Does setting it yourself not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We no longer infer username from openid strings. You must set a username if you want a username.